# Mostrar ou Ocultar Input de Acordo com Radio Button Selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Tenho um html onde quero ocultar ou exibir alguns campos de acordo com o `button radio` selecionado. Porém não tem funcionado, gostaria de uma ajuda. Segue o código:

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3, #input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").hide();
});

$("input:radio[name=custom_field-account-1]").on("change", function () {   
    if($(this).val() == "1")
    {
        $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3").show(); 
        $("#input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").hide();
    }
    else if($(this).val() == "2")
    {
        $("#input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").show(); 
        $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3").hide();   
    }
});
</script>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-1" value="1">
            Pessoa Física
    </label>
</div>  
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-2" value="2">
            Pessoa Jurídica
    </label>
</div>      
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][4]" value="" placeholder="Razão Social" id="input-custom-field4" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed"> 
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][5]" value="" placeholder="CNPJ" id="input-custom-field5" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed"> 
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][6]" value="" placeholder="I.E" id="input-custom-field6" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">  
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][3]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field3" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">   
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim podes fazer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name^="custom_field[account][1]"]').on("change", function() {
        var chosen = this.checked && this.value == '1';
        $("#div-custom-field2, #div-custom-field3").toggle(chosen);
        $("#div-custom-field4, #div-custom-field5, #div-custom-field6").toggle(!chosen);
    }).eq(0).attr('checked', true).change();
});
```

O seletor `name^="custom_field"` indica todos os elementos cujo atributo `name` comece por `custom_field`.

Sugestão:

Podias usar classes de CSS para `hide` e `show`. Como tens na primeira linha dentro de `$( document ).ready(function() {` isso vai gerar um [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), e com CSS vinha logo escondido de inicio...

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/p9wtsn9a/

Comment: existe uma forma de esconder os campos [nesta página](http://mkgrafica.com.br/index.php?route=checkout/checkout) (este é o código que me ajudou, mas nesta página de checkout, eles aparecem bloqueados de inicio e não ocultos, adicione um produto ao carrinho e vá até a pagina).

Comment: @Wendell quais são os campos? só vejo pesquise produtos e receba promoções?

Comment: editei a resposta, é necessário adicionar um produto ao carrinho e depois ir ao link que informei, logo após clique em continuar e verá os campos cnpj, ie, bloqueados e não ocultos

Comment: @Wendell testa assim `$('[id^="input-payment-custom-field"]:disabled').closest('.form-group.custom-field').hide();`. Hoje não consigo ajudar mais, estou cheio de trabalho lamento.

Comment: não deu certo, mas obrigado pela ajuda. Quando puder olhar, o código ficou assim: [Código](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/GqwZQz).

Comment: @Wendell nesse teu codepen tem umas letras estranhas em `field`. Testa correr o que eu escrevi em cima na consola lá no site e diz se funciona.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43738/discussion-between-wendell-and-sergio).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a sua lógica você pode fazer assim:

```js
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3, #input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").hide();
          });

          $("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
              $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3").show();
              $("#input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
              $("#input-custom-field4, #input-custom-field5, #input-custom-field6").show();
              $("#input-custom-field2, #input-custom-field3").hide();
            }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-1" value="1">Pessoa Física
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-2" value="2">Pessoa Jurídica
  </label>
</div>
<input type="text" name="custom_field[account][4]" value="" placeholder="Razão Social" id="input-custom-field4" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize as classes pj e pf nos campos a serem exibidos e ocultados.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("input.pf, input.pj").hide();
     $("#id-custom_field-account-1-1").click(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            $("input.pf").show();
            $("input.pj").hide();    
        } else {
            $("input.pj").show();
            $("input.pf").hide();    
        }
     });
     $("#id-custom_field-account-1-2").click(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            $("input.pj").show();
            $("input.pf").hide();    
        } else {
            $("input.pf").show();
            $("input.pj").hide();    
        }
      });
});
</script>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-1" value="1">
            Pessoa Física
    </label>
</div>  
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="custom_field[account][1]" id="id-custom_field-account-1-2" value="2">
            Pessoa Jurídica
    </label>
</div>      
<input type="text" class="pj" name="custom_field[account][4]" value="" placeholder="Razão Social" id="input-custom-field4" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed"> 
<input type="text" class="pj" name="custom_field[account][5]" value="" placeholder="CNPJ" id="input-custom-field5" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed"> 
<input type="text" class="pj" name="custom_field[account][6]" value="" placeholder="I.E" id="input-custom-field6" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">  
<input type="text" class="pf" name="custom_field[account][3]" value="" placeholder="RG" id="input-custom-field3" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">   
<input type="text" class="pf" name="custom_field[account][2]" value="" placeholder="CPF" id="input-custom-field2" class="form-control" vk_1bc56="subscribed">
```